# Google Drive Access - Service Account or OAuth - To read/write user files

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a .NET console application that performs operations on files. I would like to allow clients to give us access to their Google Drive accounts so we can read and write files. Our console application runs as a service so there is no way for the user to interact with it and authorize our access to their Google Drive account.

I was looking at using a Google Service Account for application level authentication until I learned that a Service Account does not have access to the Google Drive folder of the user that sets up the Service Account. This sort of defeats the purpose because it is the client's Google Drive account I am looking to gain access to.

I saw a workaround posted by SO member [@pinoyyid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000753/pinoyyid) posted [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766913/287793) where the refresh token can be generated using Google's Oauth2 Playground, but I am concerned that the refresh tokens could expire and user intervention would be needed again to generate another one.

Another response mentioned the solution was to create the Service Account and then share the user's Google Drive account with the Service Account.

What is the recommended approach by Google? How best to gain access to a Google Drive account while only requiring the owner to authenticate on a one-time basis, yet allowing them the ability to revoke access at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Service Account and a stored OAuth Refresh Token are viable approaches. Each has its pros and cons.

A Service Account will work where your users only need to grant access to a specific folder which they can share to the SA. Be aware that any files the SA creates are owned by, and consume quota of, the SA. You can't "share the user's Drive account to the SA", you can only share individual folders.

Storing a RT is the more permissive option. You wouldn't use the OAuth playground as described in my answer that you referenced as that's far to clunky to ask users to go through. Instead you would need to write your own registration/authorisation service (you can use AppEngine, Lambda, etc - so it's not difficult to write and host).